# Ingress external auth: How to return original auth service error message

Tags: authentication, kubernetes, nginx, nginx-ingress

I have a `nginx ingress` and it's perfectly doing authenticating the incoming requests to a microservice.
Here is the ingress definition:

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: external-auth
  labels:
    name: external-auth
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-url: "http://auth-svc.default.svc.cluster.local:8000/auth"
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - 
    http:
      paths:
      - path: "/"
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: microservice1
            port: 
              number: 8000
```

For some reasons, I need to see the authentication error message, not this **unauthorized** html from nginx:

```html
<html>
<head><title>401 Authorization Required</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>401 Authorization Required</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>
```

As I can read in the [documentations](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/main/docs/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations.md#external-authentication), some methods are already provisioned such as letting some headers pass. But I'm curious how can I ask `Ingress` to pass the original error response body without leveraging headers.

Answer (score 0):

Based on external basic authentication [see [1](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/auth/external-auth/)] once you access with no username/password you may expect code 401. But if you test it with a valid username/password you may have a result of code 200. You may refer to [this](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/auth/external-auth/) link for this concern.

For basic authentication configuration you can also check [this link](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/auth/basic/).

Comment: thanks for your answer. My question is something else. Given I have wrong username/password, auth service returns 401 with an error describing what happened. I want user to see that response, instead of seeing a nginx error temoplate.